# GitHub OAuth applications: Requesting access token via entity body or query parameters

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, github-api

I am implementing an OAuth2-based authentication schema for a web application. According to [Section 4.1.3 of the OAuth 2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) my access token request should include the required parameters (e.g. my `client_id`) in the entity body of the request.

> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by sending the
> following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP
> request entity-body:

I'm trying to test out my code using GitHub's support for OAuth applications. According to GitHub's [developer documentation](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/), they support the OAuth authorization code grant type. But every example I can find, confirmed with my own experiments, shows that the GitHub support seems to require that these parameters need to be sent as query parameters.

Can someone clarify if (a) my understanding of GitHub's OAuth support is correct, and (b) this implementation is considered to be out of compliance with the OAuth specification?